# Is there an official Catan FAQ that is a supplement to the included rules book?

Tags: catan

I was wondering if Mayfair Games or Klus himself created an official FAQ for the base (or all versions) of the Settlers of Catan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. FAQ:

http://www.catan.com/faq.html